# Set value of variable of type empty interface{} inside a function

Tags: go

Here is the code i'm struggling to get it working. I want to set the `user` value inside func getUser which takes `interface{}` type argument.

Sample code : https://play.golang.org/p/Zlhe9VEQhnD

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    name string
}

func getUser(result interface{}) {
    result = User{name: "some name"}
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func main() {
    user := User{}
    getUser(&user)
    fmt.Println(user)   
}
```

It gives this result:

```
{some name}
{}
```

I want to changes made in the function to be reflected in main

TIA

Comment: You have to type assert to the target type and then use pointer indirection. `u, ok := result.(*User)`, then `if ok {`, you can do `*u = User{name: "some name"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface argument contains a pointer to a user struct. You have to get to that pointer using a type assertion and copy the new user struct to the target struct:

```
func getUser(result interface{}) {
    *result.(*User) = User{name: "some name"}
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```